# R: For loop only updating last element in vector

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

The logic I've followed is;

-> create a results vector with 1000 elements

-> Use a for loop that on each iteration will replace the old sample value "sorting_hat" with a new value

-> Use a if else statement to replace the i'th iteration in the results vector with a string that's dependent on the new sampled value "sorting_hat"

```
all_student_houses <- rep(0, 1000)
total_students = 1000
student_number = 1


for (student_number in total_students) {

  sorting_hat <- sample(x = 1:4, size = 1, replace = TRUE, prob = c(9/41, 8/41, 14/41, 10/41) )

  if (sorting_hat == 1) {
    all_student_houses[student_number] <- "Slytherin"
    } else if (sorting_hat == 2) {
    all_student_houses[student_number] <- "Gryffindor"
    } else if (sorting_hat == 3) {
    all_student_houses[student_number] <- "Ravenclaw"
    } else {
    all_student_houses[student_number] <- "Hufflepuff"
    }

  }
```

My vectors output after running this is:

```
>all_student_houses
[995] "0"         "0"         "0"         "0"         "0"         "Slytherin"
```

I'd expect every element of this vector to be replaced by one of the four strings in the ifelse statement, not just the last element. What is currently tripping me up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 for (student_number in 1:total_students)
```

You should specify the range for the **for loop**.

Answer (score 1):

We can try using `ifelse` here, but using `case_when` from the `dplyr` package might be even cleaner:

```
sorting_hat <- sample(x = 1:4, size = 1000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(9/41, 8/41, 14/41, 10/41))
all_student_houses <-
case_when (
    sorting_hat == 1 ~ "Slytherin",
    sorting_hat == 2 ~ "Gryffindor",
    sorting_hat == 3 ~ "Ravenclaw",
    TRUE ~ "Hufflepuff"
)
```

The key take home point here is you don't need to use a loop, if you don't want to, because there are vectorized options available such as `ifelse` and `case_when`.

Comment: Totally agree with this answer since it will be faster however I'm currently just putting together an intro to R tutorial for my team and threw together this example to introduce ifelse, for loops, etc. As you can see I'm also still learning on the job!

Comment: You should teach your term best practice from the start, I think.  But, there is nothing inherently evil with using a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably optimise your code by replacing it to following

```
#Create a named vector 
student_number <- c('Slytherin' = 1,'Gryffindor' = 2, 'Ravenclaw' = 3,
                     'Hufflepuff' = 4)
#Create all the random numbers together
sorting_hat <- sample(x = 1:4, size = 1000, replace = TRUE, 
                         prob = c(9/41, 8/41, 14/41, 10/41))
#Replace it with names
all_student_houses <- names(student_number[sorting_hat])

#Check output
head(sorting_hat)
#[1] 2 2 2 4 3 2

head(all_student_houses)
#[1] "Gryffindor" "Gryffindor" "Gryffindor" "Hufflepuff" "Ravenclaw"  "Gryffindor"
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now your `for` loop runs once time. You should use:

```
for (student_number in seq(1:total_students)) {
   ...
}
```